# cmd не установливает библиотеку PyPi и модули

Tags: python

когда я через cmd хочу установть модуль PyPi,я копирую установщик - pip install...
нажимаю enter,и просто cmd зависает,при этом пишет:"pip install pycolrama"...
,и так очень долго,помогите пожалуста,что делать.

Comment: А команда "pip -V" что выдаёт?

Comment: как минимум переустановите сам pip